# Replacement of NavigationService.Navigate in Universal App

Tags: navigationservice

I am working in migration of project from windows phone 8.1 to windows universal app. 
windows phone 8.1 NavigationService can be implemented in Universal App with  several methods of Navigation like Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)); or Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), param);
But instead of having MainPage as .XAML page, I am building runtime URI in the form of string with querystring appended at end.
The similar API was available in windows phone 8.1
string strpath = "aaaaaaa";
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(strPath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

But not able to find the replacement of windows phone 8.1 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri( .. ) ) in Universal App.

Please help  .....

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement for NavigationService APIs out of the box for WinRT platform. The best you can have is use NavigationService provided in MVVM-light framework (use type), or you can build one yourself (supply the url and convert it into type).